# Override the main_template.pt without z3c.jbot

Tags: plone, zope

I want to override the original main_template of Plone without using z3c.jbot, only using ZCML directives (browser:page?).

Is there a way to override a default Plone4 template only using ZCML?

Comment: The `main_template` file is a skin method, so you wouldn't override it with jbot *or* ZCML; you'd put one in your own skin layers.

Comment: z3c.jbot supports items in skin layers, so you *could* override it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZCML can be used to override views.

Older Plone templates, like main_template.pt, use portal_skins layering facilities.

More about it in here:

https://docs.plone.org/4/en/old-reference-manuals/plone_3_theming/buildingblocks/skin/layers/overview.html

- Your addon needs GenericSetup profile
- You register skin layers in GenericSetup XML
- You register skin layers in ZCML
- skin templates are overridden in the order given by portal_skins Properties tab (you can test and manage TTW after ZCML part is done)